# Camera to computer vision software on Pi

Tags: camera, computer-vision

I am working on a project wherein i need to feed images from a camera to a computer vision application on Pi. I have never worked with camera systems before.

The camera will be tasked to continuously snap images every second and store it on a designated folder on the raspberry pi. Is this a correct way to think about the setup?

Also, what kind of a cheap camera i can buy online for the purpose?

The computer vision application will take every image and try to identify the object in it.

Answer (score 2):

The official Raspberry Pi Camera module has excellent performance. It is very well supported from the Python and C programming languages.

An alternative to the official camera would be USB cameras. Interestingly cheap no-name brands might work better.
They should work well enough from C and C++. Python has some libraries like python-v4l2 but i don't know about their quality.

Do not buy cameras without USB or those needing complex SDKs. Those are completely unsupported on Raspbian Linux in most cases.